# How do I record the value of GET parameters passed to a Google form in hidden inputs?

Tags: google-forms

My question is basically the same as [this one asked on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21554204/how-do-you-get-url-parameters-in-a-google-form-using-google-apps-script), too old to migrate, but which seems to be a better fit here.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21786766/798371) (more authoritatively, [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/160000?hl=en)) suggests a way to add a visible field to a form and set its default value, but I'd like to then make that field hidden to help not confuse people who are filling out the form.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20342684/hidden-field-in-a-google-form) suggests a couple failed strategies to get hidden items, such as prefilling a deleted question or skipped page.  I have a single-page form and for UX reasons need to keep it that way.

[This snippet](https://gist.github.com/wboykinm/7374137) suggests it's possible but doesn't say how.

Comment: WBT, did you try my solution? Would that work for you? Did you probably find some alternative?

Comment: @marikamitsos Though the answer may be useful to others, I find it unsatisfactory from a UX perspective.  See my comment on the answer.

Answer (score 3):

What @Ruben mentions is correct.

Still. I believe that you can achieve what you want because you do NOT actually want to hide the field.
Frankly, I do NOT see a need to **hide** the fields from your users.

You mention:

> ...but I'd like to then make that field hidden to help not confuse
>   people who are filling out the form

Assuming I read your question correctly, the following could be the solution to your problem.

---

**How to prevent users from altering a prefilled question/field**
 or How to "*hide*" a prefilled question

- Create a question.

  1. **Make the answer multiple choice with just one option**.
  2. **Make the answer required**.
- Repeat steps 1 & 2 for as many questions as you like.
- Prefill the fields.
- Share the prefilled link of the form.

A very simple solution.

Comment: A useful approach, but still could be unnecessarily confusing to users, particularly when the fields are internal identifier strings that look like gibberish.

Comment: This is one of the approaches I took, but the problem (for me anyways) is how the data arrives in the Google Sheet Responses. Instead of getting the answers in "1 column", you'll be getting them in "20 columns" and all of the sudden you've got data going everywhere (another problem). I'm aware you could `=transpose()` this column, but this route can get messy and seems hacky... Am I understanding your answer correctly?

Comment: @Oneezy "_Instead of getting the answers in "1 column", you'll be getting them in "20 columns_" That is the default way of getting answers in Google Forms. "_you could `=transpose()`_" Entirely your choice (as with any Google Form). Has nothing to do with the issue here. If you are comfortable with coding you could have a look at the answers at: [Hidden Field in a Google form](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20342684)

Comment: @marikamitsos i don't think i described my particular issue good enough to you..i wrote a stack question last night that explains more in depth: [Google Forms SECTION Links](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42406877/301250)

Answer (score 2):

Google Forms doesn't supports hidden form fields but [Google Apps Script HTML Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/) does.

Answer (score 1):

Google forms may not support hidden fields directly, but there is an easy work around. Just create a new form page with the fields you need and then restrict access to the page with a validated check box question. The question could say something like "admin only" and the answer your validation settings check for is a secret password you set.